# CASE Statement All returning "ELSE" value

Tags: mysql, case

I have case statement in my query where I look at and validate the inputted value. I'm not sure if I have applied my case statement correctly as all outputs are returning the value from the "ELSE" part of the query. I know that my data does contain correct values that be matching the two other conditions, but even these are returning the "ELSE" value.

Below is my case statement:

```
,   MAX(CASE
        WHEN line_field_id = 2199 AND line_value REGEXP '^HSA[0][0-5][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$' AND line_value LIKE BINARY 'HSA%' THEN line_value
        WHEN line_field_id = 2199 AND line_value REGEXP '^A[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$' AND line_value LIKE BINARY 'A%' THEN line_value 
        ELSE 'INVALID' 
    END)                'scanned_value'
```

Some sample values of the two columns:

```
   row_number | line_value | line_field_id | 
    ----------+------------+---------------+
    1         |HSA014173   |2199           |
    2         |HSA013765   |2199           |    
    3         |A062345     |2199           |    
    4         |ZHR098765   |2199           |   
    5         |A062499     |2199           |   
    6         |HSA045000   |2416           |    
    7         |HSA049800   |2416           |    
    8         |A069999     |2416           |
```

Desired Result Set:

```
   row_number | Result     | line_field_id | 
    ----------+------------+---------------+
    1         |HSA014173   |2199           |
    2         |HSA013765   |2199           |    
    3         |A062345     |2199           |    
    4         |INVALID     |2199           |   
    5         |A062499     |2199           |
```

Comment: do want to write a **SELECT** statement where gives you all valid rows from a table ?

Comment: What is the type of `line_value` column? Using a type of `VARCHAR` the issue is not reproducible on my end.

Comment: I want to select all the values from the table where the line_field_id = 2199 and that match the given criteria (Uppercase HSA / A, followed by  a number of digits). If the "scanned_value" does not match the CASE statement criteria then they must be set to "INVALID".

Comment: line_value is VARCHAR(165) and line_field_id is INT(10)

Comment: When I take out the "ELSE" statement the values are returned correctly, and the values that would of shown as "INVALID" are null

Comment: Could you show the result you get and your full query structure? The `max()` makes no sense without context (e.g. the `group by`). My best guess is that you are using the `group by` wrong (or not at all), and since `Illegal` is lexigraphically ordered after anything starting with `A` or `H`, this word will be the maximum value if there is at least one illegal row in your (implicit) group. You could add e.g. a space infront of `illegal` to test this (it should then only display `illegal` (with space) if there are only illegal rows in that group). And then you should fix your query.